# Which directories should in put in new volume in Linux server Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, centos

I have read somewhere that it is best practice to divide data in different drives in Linux server. I have only remembered few things like

1. Mount `/var/www` to new Folder in  New volume so that all website data stays there
2. Also Put Logs in that Volume

Use MySQL RDS as new instance

So that Application is stateless and nothing chnages on main machine.

I could not get the idea of being stateless

How should i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of being stateless is that the instance stores no persistent data (database, user files, etc). That way you could duplicate the instance, put it behind a load balancer and scale horizontally to more traffic without duplicating persistent data.

Using multiple volumes on a stateless machine is optional. It can help if you need to increase io throughput, but outside of that it doesn't provide many advantages. It can make it more difficult if you are trying to build stateless instances since an AMI will only include the root volume.